# html5 video and firefox

Tags: firefox, video, html

So, I created a nice little html5 video player with a playlist and some jQuery transitions between the playlist view and the video view. It works great in Chrome/Safari. However, firefox is a different story. All the jQuery business works just fine; however, the videos do not display. Rather, I am left with a grey-x. I've tried switching from straight ogg to ogv format which does not work either.

When I go straight to the file the browser attempts to download it rather then play it.
I saw a similar post on this forum where it was a problem with the MIME settings and he fixed it somehow. I'm not sure if that is the same problem for me - so a little help would be muchly appreciated.

You can check it out [here](http://erinfoote.com/8mm.html)

Here is the entire code for the page; including all jQuery functions.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Erin Foote \\ Copywriter - 8mm Stories</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //init settings
    $('#close-btn').css({'visibility' : 'hidden'});

    //$('#preLoader').css({'visibility' : 'visible'});
    //-------Text-to-Image Replacement-------\\
    //replacing h1 and h2 with coresponding images
    //using different replace method to keep client name/occupation SEOed
    $('#menu h1').each(function() {
        string = $(this).text();
        filename = string.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-').replace(/([^0-9a-z-])/g,'');
        $(this).html('<img src="images/header-' + filename + '.png" />')
        $('#vid h1').css({
        'position' : 'relative',
        'top' : '-20px'
        });
    });

    //typography for video menu
    $('#menu ul li:odd').css({'text-align' : 'right'});

    //set up selection class for videos
    $('#menu ul li a').click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });

    //set up close function on close-btn
    $('#close-btn').click(function() {

        //fade in the video and the close button
        $('#vid video').animate({opacity : 0}, 1000);
        $('#close-btn').animate({opacity : 0}, 1000);

        //fade out menu/title
        $('#menu').delay(500).animate({opacity : 1}, 1000);
        $('#menu').css({'visibility' : 'visible'}).delay(500).animate({opacity : 1}, 1000);

        //remove selected class from just watch li a
        $('#menu ul li a').removeClass('selected');

        //remove video from dom
        $('#videoCont video').remove();
   });
});

function getVideo()
{
    var browser;
    var fileExt;
    var string;
    var filename;

    //detect browser and match proper extension
    if($.browser.mozilla) {
        browser = 'gecko';
        fileExt = 'ogv';
    }
    else if($.browser.msie) {
        browser = 'trident';
         fileExt = 'mp4';
    }
    else if($.browser.opera) {
        browser = 'presto';
        fileExt = 'ogv';
    }
    else if($.browser.safari) {
        browser = 'web-kit';
        fileExt = 'mp4';
    }

    //grab filename from html and grab file from server
        string = $('#menu .selected').text();
        filename = string.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-').replace(/([^0-9a-z-])/g,'');


    //fade out menu/title
    $('#menu').animate({opacity : 0}, 1000);

    //get and place video video
    //(seeing that gecko browsers don't handle the expanded video tag well
    // and webkit browsers dont seem to handle the shorter video tage
    // we must find out which browser the user is using and append the right video tag and info

    if(browser == 'gecko') {    
        $('#videoCont').html('<video width="640" height="480" src="/work/video/' + filename + '.' + fileExt + '"></video>');
    }
    else {
        $('#videoCont').html('<video class="preload" width="640" height="480" controls=""                               autoplay="autoplay"><source src="work/video/' + filename + '.' + fileExt + '" type="video/' + fileExt         + '"></video>');
    } 

    //fade in the video and the close button
    $('#vid video').delay(500).animate({opacity : 1}, 1000);
    $('#close-btn').delay(500).css({'visibility':'visible'}).animate({opacity : .6}, 1000);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<video src="acting-art-director.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
your browser does not support the video tag
</video>

<div id="vid">
    <div id="menu">
        <h1>8mm Stories</h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:getVideo();">Yacht</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:getVideo();">pink</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:getVideo();">he cared</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:getVideo();">footerexia</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:getVideo();">the answer</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:getVideo();">yummy</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:getVideo();">teeth</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:getVideo();">moms</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:getVideo();">i am smiling</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:getVideo();">head over heals</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:getVideo();">presents</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:getVideo();">the shoes and tattoos remain</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:getVideo();">the doctor</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:getVideo();">acting art director</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:getVideo();">the sound they made</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:getVideo();">the reason</a></li>
        </ul>

        <a href="index.html" class="home">home</a>
    </div>

    <div id="close-btn">x</div>
    <div id="videoCont"></div>
</div>

<div id="girl"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Does the .ogv video play in Firefox without the jquery? That should indicate if it is a server configuration problem.

Comment: I'd encourage you to check out some of the existing html5 video javascript libraries <http://praegnanz.de/html5video/index.php>, which may help with browser compatibility, flash fall-back, and other issues.

Comment: Can you give an example url of one of the ogg video files?  I'm not seeming to get one offered when I visit the site you linked to.

Comment: @sdwilsh - on the live page it will place a flash instead of html5 video for non-webkit browsers.

Comment: @cbeer, I know you can code the whole video tag with different sources but it feels messy to me to stack the videos. Maybe Im not thinking about it in the right way.

Comment: @cbeer - you bring up a good point about the video working outside of jQuery. Will see if that is the issue and check back.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was neither a coding nor a FireFox issue - it was actually an problem with the GoDaddy IIS - they do not have any of the Theora MIME types.

To fix create a web.config file with the new MIMEs in it and upload to the root of your hosting server.
Works perfectly.

Comment: Well, you get what you pay for really. At least you can edit it with a web.config.